# How to copy-past block into content of dynamic block

Tags: terraform

For a list

```
locals{
    x = [ {  yyy = { a=1 } }, {  yyy = { b=2 }  }   ]
}
```

I want to "copy-past" block yyy into content{} section of a dynamic block

```
   dynamic "test" {
      for_each = local.x
      content {
         zzz {x.yyy}
      }
   }
```

So the result should be

```
test{
  zzz {a=1}
}

test{
  zzz {b=2}
}
```

Is it possible without manually coping each field:

```
  content {
     zzz {
        a=ifnotnull(x.yyy.a)  
        b=ifnotnull(x.yyy.b)  
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need another `dynamic` for the inner block.

But you must specify the attributes (the names) in the block. So assuming the possible attributes in the `zzz` block are `a` and `b`, something like this should work:

```
dynamic "test" {
  for_each = local.x

  content {
    dynamic "zzz" {
      for_each = [test.value.yyy]

      content {
        a = lookup(zzz.value, "a", null)
        b = lookup(zzz.value, "b", null)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the `yyy` map is not needed, so if you control the structure of the input data, it could be just `x = [ { a=1 }, { b=2 } ]`, and the inner iterator `for_each = [test.value]`.

Comment: Yes, it will work. But how to do this without setting a and b in the content{}? I want a generic solution - copy yyy as a black box, with no knowledge what parameters it contains.

Comment: I don’t think that’s possible. But you always know what attributes the block accepts, so you can add them all with the same `lookup` way.

Comment: I also think it is not possible due to security reason. Copying "black box" you can easily make a mistake with disastrous consequences